# Full text search and variable binding using postgres and jOOQ not working

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I am trying to do a full text search in a postgres database using jOOQ. The following line works:

```
Result res = pgContext.select()
                      .from(products.PRODUCTS)
                      .where("to_tsvector(title || ' ' || description || ' ' || tags) @@ to_tsquery('" + query + "')")
                      .fetch();
```

But when I add variable binding, to protect from SQL injection, I no longer get results:

```
Result res = pgContext.select()
                      .from(products.PRODUCTS)
                      .where("to_tsvector(title || ' ' || description || ' ' || tags) @@ to_tsquery('?')", query)
                      .fetch();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks and good day

Comment: Try `... to_tsquery(?) ...` -- the binding mark `?` won't work inside a literal.

Comment: Ah thanks, that was it. such a simple fix.

Comment: @pozs: You should create an answer from this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @posz did not post his comment as an answer, and it has been quite a while, I'll post his reply as an answer myself for clarity.

> Try ... to_tsquery(?) ... -- the binding mark ? won't work inside a
>   literal.